# If any static variables are destroyed, are they all destroyed?

Tags: java, android, static, null, destroy

If any static variables are destroyed, are they all destroyed? This is the code I have in my `OnCreate` method:

```
if (!LoadedData)
{
    LoadedData = true;
    SaveData = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    LoadData();
    if (MainActivity.ScreenWidth == 0 && MainActivity.ScreenWidthLandscape == 0)
        MainActivity.LoadData();
}
```

The first time my class runs, LoadedData will have the default value of false, causing any values saved to be loaded and stored in the static variables. After the device is rotated, this code will not run because all the values needed are kept in static variables, so it would be inefficient to load them again. The problem is, if some static variables are destroyed, but not all, then my program will likely crash. When static variables are destroyed, will they hold the default values? Eg integer = 0, boolean = false etc.

I have no way to test for static variables being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking a static variable for one class will tell you if that class has been destroyed or not.  That means you can know if the other variables **in that class** are still ok.  It tells you nothing about other static variables in other classes.

If `LoadedData` has been destroyed, it will be because nothing is referring to the class that contains it. The class has been finalized and garbage collected.  The entire class will be reinitialized when the system loads it again.

Comment: Perfect! My code will work correctly then because `LoadData()` only loads static variables from the current class, and when static variables have been destroyed in `MainActivity` this will return true: `if (MainActivity.ScreenWidth == 0 && MainActivity.ScreenWidthLandscape == 0)`. I just need to move that check to before this line: `if (!LoadedData)`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When your device is rotated or destroyed by Android your entire app is destroyed and itl all variables need to be reinitialized.

Comment: When my device is rotated the static variables are kept. I have my program working perfectly for rotation. The problem is, if my application is interrupted and the phone becomes low on memory, the static variables might be destroyed. Is checking the value of one of my static variables enough to determine if they have been destroyed? If the static variable `LoadedData` has been destroyed, will all my static variables have their default value, including `MainActivity.ScreenWidth` and `MainActivity.ScreenWidthLandscape`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the complete App gets destroyed. I think its only the Activity. And that Activity is then relaunched.

To your variables. If they are member variables of your class they get destroyed if the class finishes (gets destroyed).
Otherwise (variables are not members of any class) you might consider making them as class variables as global variables aren't good code.

Comment: All my static variables are class variables. I have read in a few different sources, that the static variables can be destroyed when the app is interrupted and the memory becomes low. The problem is I have a situation that I need to code for and have no way to test.